# Issue with multiple match statements, results no rows for valid patterns

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to created a graph in Neo4j with Agents and "KNOWS"
 relationship.

```
Match (a:AGENT {name:'a'})
Match (e:AGENT {name:'e'})
Match d1 = (a) -[r1:KNOWS]-> (e)
Match d2 = (a) -[r1:KNOWS]-> (x) -[r2:KNOWS]-> (e)
Return d2
```

Given: 
d1 ran independently returns no rows.
d2 ran independently returns a valid result

When I run the above code though (with both the statements), the result is no rows. WHY IS d2 getting impacted by d1 resulting in no rows?

I am new to cypher and neo4j,kindly help.

Below is the DB set up at the official neo4j console:
http://console.neo4j.org/r/617mrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d1` returns no data because there is no single hop path from `a` to `e`. Since none of you matches are optional you get no data back for the entire query.

This will cause d1 to find a match.

```
match (a:AGENT {name:'a'})
, (e:AGENT {name:'e'})
, d1 = (a) -[r1:KNOWS*..2]-> (e)
return d1
```

This is your original with a slight modification to return data.

```
match (a:AGENT {name:'a'}), (e:AGENT {name:'e'})
, d2 = (a) -[r1:KNOWS]-> (x) -[r2:KNOWS]-> (e)
optional match d1 = (a) -[r1:KNOWS]-> (e)
return d2
```

Comment: match (a:AGENT {name:'a'}), (e:AGENT {name:'e'}) -  Using  comma in match will affect on performance.

Comment: This query does work but what I was looking for is to have a query that will kind of find the shortest path(s) between two AGENTS. I went about implementing a logic in the script that calls the query to check for a valid output and call the cyphers in order of d1,d2,d3 .... (d1 = degree 1 connection). Let me know if there is a better approach and if this can be done with a single cypher query instead of trying d1,d2,d3,d4. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you are just looking for all of the shortest paths between two agents I would just use `AllShortestPaths`.   `match (a:AGENT {name:'a'})
, (e:AGENT {name:'e'})
, p=AllShortestPaths(a-[:KNOWS*..3]->e)
return p, length(p) as degrees`.  The `..3` allows you to set a maximum number of degrees between agents.

Comment: Excellent! This works like a charm! Thanks for the help Dave, this is certainly a much cleaner and efficient way  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
MATCH d2=(a:AGENT { name:'a' })-[r1:KNOWS]->(x)-[r2:KNOWS]->(e:AGENT { name:'e' })
optional match d1 = (a) -[r:KNOWS]-> (e)
RETURN d2
```

Is this what you needed?